# How to use redis server in Amazon Ec2 correctly

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, ruby-on-rails-5

I have installed the Redis server on the Amazon EC2 instance.
Redis is working fine on the server
Now I want to open the port 6379 for it "Edit inbound rules" in the security group
can you please tell me Type and protocol for it I should use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to open allow inbound access on port 6379 with **Custom TCP Protocol** from your source machine. This worked for me while implementing Redis for my database.